# How to change the baseline of an UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How would you change the baseline of any text entered in a UITextField?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the baseline of individual letters and words within the field or all at once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The precise answer eludes me, but you can set the textField's vertical content alignment like this:

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```